# Stopping apache worker of a vhost

Tags: apache-2.4, mpm-worker

Apache runs in `worker` mod. Multiple `vhosts` are configured. On of the vhosts runs in a loop, spawning childs. I want to kill this one while keeping the other good vhosts running. An `apache2ctl restart` is graceful and thus the looping requests of the bad vhost are not killed. `apache2ctl stop` stops the bad requests of the badly configured vhost, but also the other good vhosts.

Is there a way to just stop the bad vhost (or the bad requests of it)?

Comment: I misunderstood log messages like `proxy_util.c ... initialized pool in child $FQDN` `proxy_util.c ... initializing worker $URL` or `proxy_util.c ... initialized single connection worker in child $FQDN`. These *are not* requests but some kind of preconfiguring of workers. The $FQDN resp. $URL is taken from `ProxyPass` or/and `ProxyPassReverse` of the `VirtualHost` conf. If one wants to stop seeing this logs one has to remove the vhost or outcomment the `ProxyPass` directives before restarting. Don't know if this question is valid, though, I will leave it open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not workers for specific vhosts. Any worker can handle any request for any vhost.

But if you are having a problem with a vhost, you can certainly remove its configuration and then run `apachectl graceful` (or `apache2ctl` on Debian systems). No need to do a full `restart`. But requests for that virtual host would then be processed by the default virtual host, which might not be what you want.

Instead of reconfiguring Apache you should resolve the underlying problem (which you didn't really describe).

Comment: Thx! It just happened that apache did seem to hang (not serving/proxying anymore) and even a graceful restart didn't help. Only full restart did help. A look into logs revealed the "proxy/worker/child" messages which I assume had something to do with the "hanging" (see my comment at my question). CPU-Load was ok, Unfortunately I didn't do "apache2ctl status" to check if maybe the worker max (and/or other) number had exceeded the limits.